# What is the SQL*PLUS command to return view definition through remote link?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I know I can view the view definition owned by the current user by executing

```
select view_name, text from user_views where view_name like '%VIEW_NAME%';
```

How do I tweak that command to work with a DBLINK? I am trying the following but it fails with ORA-00942, table or view does not exist.

```
select view_name, text from user_name.user_views@dblink where view_name like '%VIEW_NAME%';
```

How can I select the view definition for a view through a DB Link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading [this blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/mandalika/entry/oracle_extracing_the_table_index) I came up with the answer below.

SYNTAX from post

```
SQL> select TEXT
     FROM DBA_VIEWS
     where OWNER = '<owner_name>'
     and VIEW_NAME  = '<view_name>';
```

To view the creation statement through a DBLINK you can search `all_views` through the following command;

```
select view_name, text from all_views@db_link where view_name like '%NAME%';
```

This will take you through all views on the schema instead of only the views the user has access to. If I find a way to limit the query to only the user I will update my answer.